# Set max rows in mySQL and auto truncate

Tags: mysql, truncate

I'm wondering if MySQL supports the ability to set max rows in a table and auto truncate old entries.  Let's say I have the following table and I want max rows of 5.

```
| ID | VALUE |
| 0  | value |
| 1  | value |
| 2  | value |
| 3  | value |
| 4  | value |
```

Then, another row is added, with ID 5, so I'd want ID 4 to drop and ID 5 to be added to the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). Check the count of values each time you get an insert.

You may have to map the table out to a temp folder and copy it back in with the rotated list but 5 values would make this a pretty cheap operation.